# License alerts in sandbox site

Tags: license

I just deployed a site (still under work) on a `sandbox` subdomain (https://sandbox.site-name.org/) and I am getting license problems alerts. Also, the site is user/password protected (Apache basic auth, htpasswd).

The complaining plugins are `verbb\comments` and `craft\commerce`. Is this normal? Should I worry? How can I get rid of those alerts?

Answer (score 1):

According to "[How License Enforcement Works](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/how-craft-license-enforcement-works#how-do-we-determine-craft-is-running-on-a-public-domain)" a subdomain with 'sandbox' should work fine without Craft complaining about your license.

> 4. Does it have a dev-sounding subdomain (e.g. ‘craftdemo’, ‘dev’, ‘local’, ‘loc’, ‘qa’, ‘test’, ‘testing’, ‘sandbox’, ‘stage’, ‘staging’, ‘uat’, ‘acc’ or ‘acceptance’)?

Try contacting support thru the Craft control panel about this. If it's not working properly, I think they can at least add your domain to an allowlist.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Weird as it may sound, the Alerts just went away without doing nothing.